# Different expression for “in front of the computer“

Tags: prepositions, expressions

A friend of mine asked me to read through his keywords for a presentation. He wanted to express that he sometimes eats **in front of** the computer. His sentence was:

> “I eat **at** the computer.“

Can we use **at** in this case? It sounds a bit strange to me, but we also eat **at the table**, right? Does it convey the same meaning? Is there a different way to express “I eat in front of the computer“?

Comment: Yes, we sometimes use [this construction](http://bfy.tw/B8n0).

Comment: Not worth an answer, but an interesting slang phrase I've heard recently to refer to this (at work) is [al desko](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/al_desko)

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix: That's interesting. I like that phrase!

Answer (score 1):

"at" can indeed be used to mean "in front of" but here it means something else:

[sitting or standing close to something, especially in order to do something](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/at)

- Lambert was seated at the piano.
- He was at his desk writing something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does that mean you don't think 'at' is the best choice in this case? Can you think of other ways to express that he eats in front of the computer?

Comment: @HarmlessPsycho "at" is the perfect preposition.

Comment: @HarmlessPsycho We might consider **"before"** but it would see strange to me. Although it has a meaning *in front of* I wouldn't use it in this context.